# How to use an .env variable in Vite with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment-variables, vite

I've an `.env` file with the following variable:

```
VITE_GIPHY_KEY=abcdfg
```

And I'm trying to use that `.env` variable in `src/main.ts` like this:

```
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_GIPHY_KEY);
```

I get `undefined` in the console. How can I use `.env` variables in Vite with TS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I renamed `.env` to `.env.local`

Second, only variables prefixed with `VITE_` are exposed to your Vite-processed code.
Example:

```
VITE_SOME_KEY=123
DB_PASSWORD=foobar

console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY) // 123
console.log(import.meta.env.DB_PASSWORD) // undefined
```

Source: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files

Comment: I don't know why only works with .env.local, so if somebody explain that + give an answer similar to mine, I gonna give the "accepted answer" and upvote.